# Extracting audio from video files

Tags: matlab, audio, video

I just received a 30 day trial of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, and I just tested it out. I found this code [online](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-extract-and-interpret-audio-from-a-video-file-using-MATLAB) that separates video from audio:

```
file='movie.AVI';
file1='targetfile.wav';

hmfr= video.MultimediaFileReader(file,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
hmfw = video.MultimediaFileWriter(file1,'AudioInputPort',true,'FileFormat','WAV');

while ~isDone(hmfr)
audioFrame = step(hmfr);
step(hmfw,audioFrame);  
end

close(hmfw);
close(hmfr);
```

but I can't run it, I only get the error:
 `Undefined variable "video" or class "video.MultimediaFileReader".`
I'm not quite sure what this means, does it refer to my code or the computer vision system toolbox? I checked, I have all the requirements and the add-on manager says it's properly installed, so I'm not quite sure why I get this error.

Comment: If anyone was wondering I got the code from here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-extract-and-interpret-audio-from-a-video-file-using-MATLAB

Comment: Because [that class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html) is part of the [`vision`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/systemobjectslist.html) package namespace, not `video`.

Comment: The documentation associated with the toolbox says that video.MultimediaFileReader (and Writer) is a supported system object. Is that the same thing?

Comment: Wow you're right I was looking at the 2010 documentation in the add-on explorer

Comment: so it would be vision.VideoFileWriter instead of video.MultimediaFileWriter instead, right?

Comment: I assume so.  I've never used the packages, but I could also not find any references to `video.` past R2010a.

Comment: Ugh that makes total sense - thanks for the help. Once I finish the code tomorrow I'll post the updated version of the code in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your task is quite easier than you think it is. It can be done without any reliance on toolboxes.

That's how:-

**1.** Read your video file and get its sample rate using **[`audioread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html)**.

**2.** Then use [**`audiowrite`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) to write it as an audio file.

```
[input_file, Fs] = audioread('movie.AVI');
audiowrite('target_file.WAV', input_file, Fs);

%If your path is set to default then MATLAB may give you 'Permission Denied' Error. 
%Change the path or give different full path like: 'D:\target_file.WAV' while audiowriting
```

Comment: This is correct! I can't believe I missed that! @rayryeng the documentation is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html says: audioread can extract audio from MPEG-4 (.mp4, .m4v) video files on Windows 7 or later. Thank you all so much for your help. I will, however, put that the 2010b video documentation is in my question.

Comment: @Mia ! and also from .wmv and .avi files on Windows 7 or later and Linux!